# What happens when there is Vish Yoga (moon saturn conjunction) in the Mithuna/Gemini ascendant chart in the ashtam bhav ? For example in chart below

Tags: astrology, kundali

What happens when there is Vish Yoga (moon saturn conjunction) in the Mithuna/Gemini ascendant/Lagna chart in the ashtam bhav (8th house)? For example in chart below. We can also see the angles (degrees) below

[image]

Comment: In this chart (Gemini Asc) the Moon-Sat conjunction is in the 8th house, not the 10th. You have to count houses from the Lagna. It is the 10th Rasi in Kalpurusha's Kundali, i.e., Capricorn. In this chart, the 10th house is the 12th Rasi, i.e., Pisces, which is empty.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. Corrected it in the question.